# How to read a 14 bit digit from a SPI interface

Tags: binary

I am trying to read temperature data from a temperature conditioning chip and it says that the data is formatted as the first 14-bits of a 32 bit number. I understand the sign and the main part and the decimal part. But I cannot understand bit number 20. I thought it was a decimal place holder, but its value changes when they gave examples for the format. You can see that for +1600.00 --> 0110 0100 0000 00  and for +25.0 --> 0000 0001 1001 00. What does the 3rd bit from the left represent??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D20 is the 1's position (2^0).

```
D31 = Sign bit
D30 = 2^10 = 1024
D29 = 2^9  =  512
D28 = 2^8  =  256
D27 = 2^7  =  128
D26 = 2^6  =   64
D25 = 2^5  =   32
D24 = 2^4  =   16
D23 = 2^3  =    8
D22 = 2^2  =    4
D21 = 2^1  =    2
D20 = 2^0  =    1
D19 = 2^-1 =    0.5
D18 = 2^-2 =    0.25
```

Comment: But it says that D31 is the sign bit in the figure?

Comment: Ok, I see it now. so it is actually D30:D20, which are 11 bits all together. Thanks!